# C - Print text from file, scroll with enter

Tags: c, file

I want to write a method which prints out the content of a file.

My method looks like this:

```
void showFile(char* src) {
char output[100];
char a = 0;
FILE *file;
int i = 0;

file = fopen(src, "r");
do {
    system("cls");
    for (i = 0; i < min(24, filelength(src)-i); i++) {
        fgets(output, 24, file);
        printf("%s", output);
    }
    printf("\nNaechste Seite mit <Enter> ausgeben\n");
    a = _getch();
} while (a == 13 && i < filelength(src)-1);
printf("\n\n");
fclose(file); 
file = NULL;
}
```

It just needs the filepath the file is stored in as a String.

the min() method looks like this, it returns the smaller value:

```
int min(int x, int y) {
if (x > y) {
    return y;
}
else {
    return x;
}
}
```

Now my problem is, when a file looks like this for example:

```
This
Is
The
Files
Content
```

It results in something like that:

```
This
Is
The
Files
Content
Content
Content
Content
Content
Content
Content
Content
Content
```

And so on. I don't know where exactly the problem is. I hope someone else can figure out my failure that I am unable to see?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the `filelength()` function doing?

Comment: Another thing, you `min(24, filelength(src)-i)` lines, which is not correct. Do you really want to print at least 24 lines? Shouldn't it be `max(24, filelength(src)-i)`?

Comment: `filelength()` must be the problem -- I bet it does not return the length in *lines* but in *bytes*. Therefore, the loop does not see it should end, `fgets` fails and you don't check it, and thus it prints the last contents of `output`.

Comment: `filelength` is a standard function and definitely **does** return the filelength in bytes.

Comment: Note that `static inline int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }` is a sensible use of the ternary operator, and can be one line or four lines according to taste, either of which is shorter and ultimately easier to read than the eight line function you have.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I think you got that a bit wrong... min returns the **smaller** value of both.

Comment: @PhilippMurry Ah yes, I did.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If OP is developing for DOS (his program looks like this) he might not have access to a C99 compiler; C89 does not have the `inline` keyword.

Comment: filelength() is a method that counts the file's rows until EOF

Comment: @FUZxxl: That's a possibility (that the OP's compiler does not support `inline`), in which case, delete the `inline` keyword.  It is only a hint to the compiler (one which would likely be taken in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the length of the file in advance; you can show batches of 24 lines until you run out of text to show. By the way, you also assume all of the lines fit on a single line on screen. Here is an alternative that will work even if that's not the case:

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 79

void showFile(char* src)
{
    char output[SCREEN_WIDTH+2];
    FILE *file;
    int i, a = 0;

    file = fopen(src, "r");
    if (!file) return;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            if (!fgets(output, SCREEN_WIDTH, file))
               break;
            printf("%s", output);
            if (output[strlen(output)-1] != '\n')
               printf ("\n");
        }
        if (i == 24)
        {
            printf("\nNaechste Seite mit <Enter> ausgeben\n");
            a = _getch();
        } else
            a = 0;
    } while (a == 13);
    printf("\n\n");
    fclose(file); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay attention to the return status from `fgets()`, which is NULL when there is no more data (you've reached EOF).  Even though your loop would read more lines, there aren't any to read and it should stop.

You get the same data over and over again because `fgets()` typically doesn't modify its string if it has got EOF on the input stream it is reading from.  You might use this for the inner loop, which has a variety of clean-ups applied (one courtesy of [Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta) — removing `filelength()` which measures the file size in bytes instead of lines, so the values 24 and the file length are incommensurate, and anyway that function is not something you want to call on each iteration of the loop for reasons of efficiency as well).

```
for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    if (fgets(output, sizeof(output), file) == 0)
        break;
    printf("%s", output);
}
```

You may need to detect EOF in the outer loop too.  Just for once, it might even be reasonable to use `feof(file)` there, seeing as how the outer loop is a `do … while` loop.